# duplicate calculator, network and universal access icons after software update

Tags: updates, slingshot

I have duplicate icons for the calculator, universal access and network icons in the applications menu and system settings windows after performing a software update.

How do I get rid of the duplicates? Is there a way to manually edit the slingshot-launcher database?

Comment: Do you have added a new ppa?

Comment: Yes I have added PPAs for syncthing, vivaldi-beta, tox and enpass, but this only happened after performing a system software update none of these aforementioned PPAs should have added any of the duplicate icons.

Comment: I should clarify that the duplicates only appear when searching the applications menu, as opposed to browsing it. So it must me something with the search database.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, but the icons that are showing duplicates in the slingshot search are not in /usr/local/share/applications OR "myuser"/.local/share/applications So any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got rid of the duplicates by removing the superflous symlinks in `/usr/local/share/applications`